# Two dimensional arrays in JNI

Tags: java, c++, multidimensional-array, java-native-interface

I have started working with JNI. in which i want to return two dimensional array from a cpp method and retrive in java. I have got the information for single dimensional array as follow:

```
JNIExport jint JNICALL Java_IntArray_sumArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
```

**can any one specify how to return two dimensional arrays from cpp and retrieve in java jni?**

**EDIT**
i have tried following

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
 Java_ObjectArrayTest_initDouble2DArray(JNIEnv *env,
                                    jclass cls,
                                    )
 {
     jobjectArray result;
     int i;
     jclass doubleArrCls = **(*env)**->FindClass(env, "[D");
...
 }
```

but it gives an error that  error C2819: type 'JNIEnv_' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please go through this post for understanding how to return 2D arrays from C++

[C++-2D array](https://electrofriends.com/articles/jni/jni-part-5-jni-arrays/)

Comment: You don't need the * before env.If you remove it, then it works.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out.

Comment: JNI-2D array link does not work anymore, consider adding the info in the anwser

Comment: Great example as to why link-only answer have poor value... The second link in your answer is dead, so this answer is worthless in its current state.

Comment: Sevan and a half years later and you still leave it as a link-only array after it's already gone stale once?