# Access 2D array field in C++ using JNI

Tags: android, arrays, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Java class like this:

```
class Blah{
    float[][] params;
}
```

In JNI I tried getting params like this:

```
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jfieldID paramsFid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "params", "[[F;");
jobjectArray paramArray = (jobjectArray)env->GetObjectField(obj, paramsFid);
```

but it always fails on GetObjectField, I find no specialized functions for 2D array so I'm just treating it as an object and cast it to an object array. Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two dimensional arrays in JNI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168989/two-dimensional-arrays-in-jni)

Comment: this is not a duplicate. The referenced post mentions a similar but different problem. I did not find any reference online for getting 2D array from a field.

Comment: Is `paramsFid` valid? Use LogCat functions to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetFieldID` call looks like it is returning null. You need to remove that semicolon in the type so it looks like:

```
jfieldID paramsFid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "params", "[[F");
```

The semicolon is used at the end of class names, not primitive types.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html) is a good reference on JNI types.